# local xml parsing in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing local xml file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723636/parsing-local-xml-file-in-android)

Hi every one, In this folowing link there is a xml parser

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser/#idc-cover

instead of using
url can i use the xml file stored locally, means inside "res/xml/*.xml"
can any one provide me a code for dat...(am brand new to android, pls help me)

Answer (score 1):

try using assest folder like this

```
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream stream = null;

    try {

        stream = assetManager.open("sample.xml");

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // handle

    }
```

and use this

```
xr.parse(stream);
```

stream object instead of

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

One thing more: [download this file](http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml) and use above code  put this file in ur assest folder

Comment: thanx for ur reply,if u hav any similar sample code ill u give me zip file of the same,,,

Comment: I had done xml parsing but mine requirements are different from yours its better you spend some time with link that you posted and rest what you have to do is already mentioned by me

Comment: @Sowmya: stop buzzing around asking for code! Saurabh also gave you the same suggestion as I did. try to work it out yourself first. if you're stuck at some points, you can always come back here with your exact problem and ask.

Comment: thank u saurabh,, finally i solved my problem from u,,keep suggesting

Comment: anytime, one thing more if u got the answer mark the post as answered by clicking correct tick

Answer (score 0):

Refer this Question [Parsing local XML file using Sax in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728064/parsing-local-xml-file-using-sax-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void parseData()
    {
         SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
         SAXParser sp = null;
        try {
            sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         // Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created.
         XMLReader xr = null;
        try {
            xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         // Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader
        OfficesParser myExampleHandler = new OfficesParser();
         xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

         // Parse the xml-data from our URL. 
         try {



                        File f = new File("MyLocal.xml");
            xr.parse(new InputSource(new URL(f.toURL()).openStream()));

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            //Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            //Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.d("Net Disconnected", "NetDisconeeted");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: thanx for ur reply,,i tried ur code but i didnt get out put,,if u hav any similar code ill u pls give me zip file of that project,,thanx in advance